# How to make label or image dynamic in tableviewcell?

Tags: swift

I want to make tableview cell have dynamic label or image in it. I don't want to loop add subview to content view of tableview cell because it will run slow when you scroll. So can anyone help me please? Like this image:

[image: Like this image]

My code is;
[image]

Comment: What code have you tried? Please post it! http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjdUj.png

Comment: i try to do it but it not smooth

Comment: No. I meant could you post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the context of your code, something like this can work:

**NOTE** This will work on iOS <= 8

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var TableVC: UITableView!

    let elements = ["item1 item2 item3","item1 item2", "item1"]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.TableVC.delegate = self
        self.TableVC.dataSource = self


        self.TableVC.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.





    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

     return elements.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)



        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0



      cell.textLabel?.attributedText = addTextToAttribute(text: elements[indexPath.item])




        return cell
    }



    func addTextToAttribute(text : String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {


      let mutString = NSMutableAttributedString()

     let  s = text.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
        let attr: [String: AnyObject] = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)]

        for text in s {


        mutString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "-" + text + "\n", attributes: attr))
        }


        return mutString
    }

}
```

[image]